# Запятая перед "что" (союз или местоимение)

Tags: пунктуация

**Идеальным можно считать сообщение, которое не только показывает () что мы проверяем, но и почему мы это ожидаем.**

Нужна ли запятая перед "что"?

Answer (score 1):

Предложение требует редактирования, содержание неясно, грамматика неверна. Союз НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО И должен соединять однородные члены или однородные придаточные.

Условные варианты:

Идеальным можно считать сообщение, которое  показывает  **не только** что мы проверяем, **но и** почему мы это делаем.

Идеальным можно считать сообщение, которое  показывает  **не только то**,  что мы проверяем, **но и то**, почему мы это делаем.

Идеальным можно считать сообщение, которое **не только** показывает, что мы проверяем, **но и** объясняет, почему мы это делаем.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал изменить порядок слов по типу: показывает не только А, но и Б.
Тогда ясно видно, что запятая не нужна.

**Идеальным можно считать сообщение, которое показывает не только что мы проверяем, но и почему мы это (лучше - *этого*) ожидаем.**

Все равно, семантика предложения не очень мне нравится. Мы проверяем, например,  результат вычисления, а ожидаем получить число N. Утверждение "мы проверяем то, что ожидаем" неверно.

Может так?:

**Идеальным можно считать сообщение, которое показывает не только что мы проверяем, но и почему мы ожидаем получить именно такой результат.**

Comment: Ваш вариант граматически правильный. Но интересно, как ставить знаки именно в первоначальном варианте.

Comment: считать ли "что мы проверяем" придаточным изъяснительным и ставить ли запятую, если это так.

Comment: Если предложение некорректно, невозможно говорить о корректной постановке знаков препинания. Союз НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО И должен соединять однородные члены или однородные придаточные (@Arina)